# Create table in page in swift ios

Tags: swift

I need a view controller containing introductory text followed by a table with three columns and a variable number of rows on top of a specially formatted first row.

What I've done is to implement at table view controller, but that only lets me add 1 column. Does anyone know of a way to implement a more traditional "table" with lines between cells and columns?

Comment: If you can't find anything else, I guess you could create 3 different tables in a standard View Controller. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, you could check to see what table is being updated... Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the advice @penatheboss ! Was thinking the same myself, but I was hoping this was so common that there should be a more "robust" or "out of the box" solution.